# Get original sys.argv

Tags: python, argv

Is there a way to obtain the original argv value from python after execution code like this:

```
sys.argv[0]=""
```

In fact I search for the unwritable version of sys.argv.

I would prefer a OS independent solution, but I'm working on windows, so a windows only solution would be sufficient

Comment: Can you not simply *not* change the original `sys.argv`?

Comment: No, because i do not write the main code. The main code comes from an framework, and it modifies the argv

Comment: Where is the import for the framework? Can you make a copy of `sys.argv` before executing the `import`?

Comment: That could be a possibility. The framework import my code, but it is posssible that this import is done before argv is modified.

Comment: @chepner That was the right idea. In my case it was the other way around, I was able to make a copy of sys.argv at module scope, because my script was imported before the modification was done. That would be my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you could use:

```
open("/proc/{}/cmdline".format(os.getpid())).read()[:-1].split("\x00")[1:]
```

Comment: Nice solution but I'm searching for a os independent or at least windows solution

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that I'm afraid.